# Enabled binding for NSTextField bound to NSString

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsstring, nstextfield

```
@interface MyClass {
  NSString *_myString;
}
@property (copy) *myString;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myString = _myString;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
  self.myString = @"";
}
```

In the nib, I have an NSTextField and an NSButton.  The text field's Value binding is set to myClass.myString. I verified that the variable _myString is being updated correctly when text is typed into the text field.

The Enabled binding of the NSButton is set to myClass.myString.length.  However, when I start up the program, the NSButton is enabled! If I go to the textfield and type something into it, the button stays enabled.  Then if I erase the text from the textfield, the button becomes disabled.

But why isn't the button disabled to begin with, after the call in awakeFromNib ?  Do I have to do some additional work to make the binding work in the opposite direction (myClass.myString --> NSTextField) ?  I thought that declaring myString as a property would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing this but I would say the easiest way to fix it, since your text will start out empty, is in `awakeFromNib` do something like `[myButton setEnabled:false];`